# How do i get the Jquery Mobile popup to position over the marker when I open it using Openlayers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, openlayers

Below is my code.  I cleaned up and modified the addMarkers function, so i know that it is not going to work in this example but just wanted to shorten it down to show what I was doing.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to set the position of the popup.  I thought positionto: event.target would work but it is not coming back with anything in target.  Any ideas?  I want it to popup like most items do from when you click on a marker on a map.

```
 function addMarkers(json){
        for (var i=0;i<json.records.record.length;i++){

            // Make Point
            point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonLat.lon, lonLat.lat);
            feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
            layer.addFeatures(feature);
        }
        map.addLayer(layer[0]);
    }
}


var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    [vectorlayer1, vectorlayer2],
    {
        clickout: true, toggle: false,
        multiple: false, hover: false
    }
);

vectorlayer1.events.on({
    "featureselected": popup,
    "featureunselected": function(e) {
        alert("unselected feature "+e.feature.id+" on vectorlayer 1");
    }
});

 function popup(event){
    $("#popup").popup('open', {
        positionTo: event.target
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Jquery mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/options.html): 
'positionTo' parameter must be a *string* ('origin' or 'window') or a JQuery selector.
In this case $(event.target) will work.